# Controlling the streaming with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

i am using the below code to play song from server.

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(playUrl);
```

And i am calling start method from `public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)` method.
But what happens is sometimes it's buffering 5 to 6% and starts playing and sometimes it buffers 40 or 60 or sometimes 80%.
And i am using `prepareAsync ()` to prepare player. So, is there any way that I can play song after 5 or 6%?

thankx

Answer (score 0):

try setting an update buffer listener and play the video after certain percentage.
Edited:

```
    boolean mediaPrepared = false;
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
      void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
        mediaPrepared = true;
      }
    });
mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener(){
  public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent){
    if (!mediaPrepared){
      mp.prepareAsync();
    }
    if (percent > 5){
      mp.start();
    }
  }
});
```

And make sure to handle correctly the values of the `mediaPrepared` flag.

I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe you can use it as a hint. Good luck!

Comment: i have tried this but what happens if the player is not prepared than it gives an error.

Comment: Well @Hitendra, as I wrote, I'm not sure this would work, but you just can add another if-block

Comment: require a mp.reset() before the mp.prepareAsync() i think... btw not sure... the flow of the callbacks is pretty mystirus to me, it doesn't seems to follow the docs completly...